# Sockeye - FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mxnet\libmxnet.dll' (or one of its dependencies)

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, mxnet, file-not-found

I want to train the model according to

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/train-neural-machine-translation-models-with-sockeye/

I'm using Anaconda 4.10.3 (Python 3.8.8) and I had already installed Sockeye and MXNet.

As soon as I run the code:

```
python -m sockeye.train -s train.de \
                        -t train.en \
                        -vs newstest2016.tc.de \
                        -vt newstest2016.tc.en \
                        --num-embed 128 \
                        --rnn-num-hidden 512 \
                        --attention-type dot \
                        --dropout 0.5 \
                        --word-min-count 10 \
                        -o model
```

I get the error message:

> FileNotFoundError: Could not find module
> 'C:\Users\myusername\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mxnet\libmxnet.dll' (or
> one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor
> syntax.

I have no idea why the libmxnet.dll is missing.
According to https://awslabs.github.io/sockeye/setup.html I can use Python3.7 or above, but why do I have problems with MXNet and how can I fix it?